# Netty packets and setting Frames

Tags: string, authentication, netty, frame, packet

At the moment I'm developing a PacketSystem. Through that I made a authentication system and created a key that's being send as a String from the client to the server like this:

```
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Packet p) throws Exception {
    if(p instanceof PacketInServerAuthRequest) {
        System.out.println("Sending WrapperAuthKey. Waiting for answer...");
        send(new PacketOutServerAuthAnswer(NetworkUtils.readWrapperKey()));
    }
}
```

Somehow the server receives the WrapperKey three times. The two last times without a packet id and cause these two Exceptions:

```
SEVERE: Nov 19, 2017 9:56:35 PM io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline onUnhandledInboundException
WARNUNG: An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: readerIndex(8) + length(4) exceeds writerIndex(9): PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 8, widx: 9, cap: 1024)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:442)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:624)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:559)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:476)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: readerIndex(8) + length(4) exceeds writerIndex(9): PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 8, widx: 9, cap: 1024)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.checkReadableBytes0(AbstractByteBuf.java:1396)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.readInt(AbstractByteBuf.java:766)
    at me.micha.flickcloud.netty.handler.PacketDecoder.decode(PacketDecoder.java:13)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411)
    ... 16 more

SEVERE: Nov 19, 2017 9:56:35 PM io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline onUnhandledInboundException
WARNUNG: An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: readerIndex(16) + length(4) exceeds writerIndex(17): PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 16, widx: 17, cap: 1024)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:442)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:624)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:559)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:476)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: readerIndex(16) + length(4) exceeds writerIndex(17): PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 16, widx: 17, cap: 1024)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.checkReadableBytes0(AbstractByteBuf.java:1396)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.readInt(AbstractByteBuf.java:766)
    at me.micha.flickcloud.netty.handler.PacketDecoder.decode(PacketDecoder.java:13)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411)
    ... 16 more
```

After some research I found out that I may have to use LengthFieldPrepender and LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder to tell the server when the String ends but I seriously have no idea of using them. Maybe I have a mistake in sending Strings through a ByteBuf in general.

I would appreciate it if someone can solve my problem.

EDIT:
That's how I init the Channels on both sides(server&client):

```
public static Channel initChannel(Channel channel) {
    channel.pipeline()
    .addLast(new PacketDecoder())
    .addLast(new PacketEncoder());

    return channel;
}
```

Comment: There should be a way to identify frame boundary. In Netty to define frame boundaries you can add handlers to the pipeline. It would be easy to point out if you add your code which contains server/client pipeline.

Comment: Edit with code is above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that netty is an asynchronous / non-blocking framework which means the data that is read from the Channel can be fragmented (just as TCP in general). You need to ensure there is enough data to read before trying so in your `ByteToMessageDecoder` implementation. Seems like you try to read an Int and there are not 4 bytes left to read.